# Google People API: Not receiving the requested information and instead receiving etag in the response body

Tags: http, postman, google-signin, google-people-api

I am testing the Google People Api with this request:

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/111110XXXXXX08978?personFields=birthdays
```

I am sending the authorization token in the header:
[image]

The request is successful, but it is always missing the requested information.
I always receive something like this:

```
{
    "resourceName": "people/111110367350060808978",
    "etag": "%EgQBBzcuXXXXXyWXFGaz0="
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Try including the following scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. Did you try the same request (same person) in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get?apix=true) to see if you got more data from that contact?